# Yeoman generator can't find .yo-rc.json file when installed globally

Tags: javascript, json, generator, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have a simple yeoman generator that is all pretty much ready to go.
However, it is heavily dependent on the `.yo-rc.json` file, as I read important configurations from it every time I run the generator.

This works fine if I am running it from the project's directory (by project I mean the generator's project itself), but it won't find it when I am attempting to run it from another project, even with all the steps including `npm link`.

I feel like I missed something important here, but can't seem to find it in the documentation. Am I supposed to somehow set up a global `.yo-rc.json` file when my generator is installed globally? Is there a step or configuration I missed?

I doubt this is relevant, but in case it is, this is being developed run on Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.yo-rc.json` is only used for local project configuration. It is not meant to be used for global configuration.

For global configuration, you can use the `store: true` option for each prompts you want to remember with `this.prompt()`.

The reason behind this is that a user creating a new project doesn't necessarily want his previous choices applied. So the configuration is kept local to a project, so the generator can know the choices user made in the past for the current project; but not globally applied to all the other project they might created.

Comment: Ohh yes, so it was a misunderstanding from my end.
In that case I do have a follow up question: the reason I needed the config to always be read was so that the user could change at will some file paths and templates to be read from without having the prompt questions asked, and instead just using an argument setting those configurations. Would there be anyway to do this by using optional arguments instead of making a this.prompt() for them ?

Comment: @theJuls Yeoman is only Node.js code. So you can make your own implementation. We don't want to provide this in the core directly as I think it'd likely let generator author release bad UX too easily.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll check it out to see what I can do.
Thanks for the help!